# Freeware for browsing Multivalue databases/Unidata

Tags: unidata, multivalue-database

I'm looking for some free software to let me browse through the files/records in a Unidata server.

I found a program several months ago, but have no idea what it was called or where I found it.

Comment: Do you want to browse from the server or a Windows / Unix Client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [BDT (Basic Developer Toolkit)](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

Rocket's [DataVu Query](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/datavu/datavu1-1) is free, but probably not what you're thinking of.  It was released in October 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just log into the server, start up an interactive session and browse through the database that way.